# collapse bookmarks by default in dita 1.8.4

Tags: pdf, customization, bookmarks, args, dita

i have a working customization, but what i cannot figure out is, how to set the bookmarks in my pdf document to 'collapsed' by default.
i tried to paste

```
  <property name="args.bookmark.style" value="COLLAPSED" />
```

into my build file, as well as into build.xml, build_template.xml and build.properties in the plugin and customization folder.

Nothing seems to have an effect on this.

Am i missing a step?
(I have been wondering if there was something in my customization which would automatically leave the bookmarks expanded, but I do not know where to look for this... I am pretty sure this is not the problem)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out what was the problem. 
There was no need to change any ANT properties.

All it needs is to add the following attribute:

```
<xsl:attribute name="starting-state">hide</xsl:attribute>
```

in the template:

```
<xsl:template match="*[contains(@class, ' topic/topic ')]" mode="bookmark">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look in this XSLT stylesheet:

DITA-OT/plugins/org.dita.pdf2/cfg/fo/attrs/basic-settings.xsl

there is a parameter called "bookmarkStyle" which gets its value from the ANT build files.

```
    <xsl:param name="bookmarkStyle">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$antArgsBookmarkStyle!=''"><xsl:value-of select="$antArgsBookmarkStyle"/></xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>COLLAPSED</xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:param>
```

As you can see, the default value for that parameter is COLLAPSED so you should do nothing to obtain this default behavior, I tested and the bookmarks area in a generated PDF only shows the top-level topic references.
You can also add an xsl:message in that parameter and see the value it receives from the build files.

Maybe you have another expectation of what args.bookmark.style was intended to be used for.